# How to give more importance to a variable in a chart

Tags: plotting, graphics, variable

I have two variables, `x` and `y`.

`x` goes from 0 to 10, 10 being best.

`y` goes from 0 to 10, 0 being the best.

The `y` variable has more importance, say 70%, while `x` is 30%.

How can I make a graph that shows which values are better? I know (10, 0) is going to be the best, but I want to compare every possible value.

I tried doing something like:

```
y = y * 1.3
```

And using that value, but I'm sure that's not mathematically strict.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I would encourage you to add to your question the Mathematica code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a weighted average. Something like this, where a value of 10 is the best value possible

```
rating =.7 (10 - y) + .3 x;
```

You can then plot it to see how "good" different (x,y) values are:

```
Plot3D[.7 (10 - y) + .3 x, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]